# Explain the use of the Java word synchronized in a Processing sketch

Tags: java, processing, synchronized

In programs produced by the excellent G4P of [Peter Lager (aka Quark)](http://www.lagers.org.uk/index.html) the word `synchronized` frequently appears, as in the code snippet below, copied [from here](http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/2599/g4p-how-do-i-render-a-processing-object-ie-ellipse-rect-etc-onto-a-g4p-library-control-window/p1). Based on this example, I intend to use two windows in a Processing sketch, with latitude and longitude and other data displayed in the main window, and a view of the satellites in the sky in a second window. The main program will set up an array of satellite data that will be read for display in the secondary window. Later I will extend the program to record GPS data on a journey, and to produce videos of both the sky picture, and the journey. (I have done a similar project in SuperBasic on a Sinclair QL simulation, but that had disadvantages that I can overcome with Processing)

I have read [this description](http://javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_concurrency_1.shtml) of `synchronized` in Java, but can't see why it applies here. The sketch below, and other tests, appear to run with identical results whether the word is used or not.

Please can someone explain if the word `synchronized` is really needed, or might become necessary as the program expands. Are there any disadvantages to including it?

```
import g4p_controls.*;

GWindow myWindow;

    public void setup(){
      size(480, 320, JAVA2D);

      G4P.messagesEnabled(false);
      G4P.setGlobalColorScheme(GCScheme.BLUE_SCHEME);
      G4P.setCursor(ARROW);

      if(frame != null){
        frame.setTitle("Sketch Window");
      }

      myWindow = new GWindow(this, "Window title", 0, 0, 240, 120, false, JAVA2D);
      myWindow.addDrawHandler(this, "myWindowDraw");
    }

    public void draw(){
      background(100, 230, 100);
      fill(0);
      text("Main WIndow", 20 ,20);
    }

    // public void myWindowDraw(GWinApplet appc, GWinData data) {
    synchronized public void myWindowDraw(GWinApplet appc, GWinData data) {
      appc.background(100,100,200);
      appc.fill(0,0,160);
      appc.noStroke();

      appc.ellipse(appc.width/2, appc.height/2, appc.width/1.2, appc.height/1.2); 
      appc.fill(255);
      appc.text("Secondary window", 20, 20);   
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use `synchronized` if your application is not multi-threaded. However most modern processors are multi-core and rely on multi-threading in applications to achieve best performance. If your application is not, and is unlikely ever to be, high performance then you can ignore `synchronized`.

If, at some stage, you enhance your code to take advantage of multiple threads then you will need to change it to be 'thread safe'. Many programmers these days prefer to build thread safety into their code from the beginning to avoid this effort later. This is especially true for programmers who build libraries that will be used in many different ways.

In Java 8 you do have one other option for taking advantage of multi-threading. The streams libraries now explicitly support parallel streams for splitting up workloads and combining (reducing/collecting) them later. If that's likely to match your need for speed then again you can ignore synchronized and use parallel streams to take advantage of parallel processing. For example, if at some stage you need to process large amounts of GPS data to create your videos then you could potentially have a parallel stream that produces the data, processes each of the sections separately and then combines them again into a single picture. With streams that can be done without you having to manually create threads and thread safety.

Comment: Thank you sprinter, that's exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: Keep in mind: If you are coding in the default Processing IDE and don't use Processing as a core library (in Eclipse for example), the code is getting transformed to Java 4 code, which doesn't support the Java 8 additions listed above.

Comment: @teegabel I suggest anyone using an IDE that doesn't support Java 8 drop it and move to one that does. Streams are a very good addition to the language.